# Is this the way of using smtplib

Tags: python, smtplib

I am trying to send emails using python and smptplib but it shows some errors the following is my code:

```
import smtplib,ssl

 port = 456
 password = input("enter your password : ")
 email_id = input("enter your email adress: ")
 print("creating connection...")

 context = ssl.create_default_context()
 with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com",port,context=context) as server:
      server.login(email_id,password)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/rijilvarghese/Documents/email.py/newemail.py", line 9, in <module>
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com",port,context=context) as server:
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 1031, in __init__
source_address)
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
  (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 336, in connect
   self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
   File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 1037, in _get_socket
   self.source_address)
   File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 727, in create_connection
raise err
   File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 716, in create_connection
sock.connect(sa)
   OSError: [Errno 65] No route to host
```

this Are the errors,What should i do?

Comment: Are you connected to the internet ?

Comment: Yes iam connected

Comment: Is it typo or are you using port 456? The default SMTP port for implicit TLS is **465**.